# Unable to load R package MASS

Tags: r, package

I am learning R and in the session user installs `MASS` package.
It seems MASS comes as prebuilt and pre installed package in R studio.
I went to Package section unchecked MASS Package.

```
detach("package:MASS", unload=TRUE)
```

Above code got executed. I then used the install button and selected MASS package
[image: Install R package MASS]

I received the following

```
trying URL https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/MASS_7.3-45.zip
Content type 'application/zip' length 1085995 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps*****\downloaded_packages
```

While trying to load the MASS package I am getting the below error. Please help in providing solution to this.

```
> library("MASS", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library")
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/MASS/R/MASS.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MASS’
> library(MASS)
Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/MASS/R/MASS.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘MASS’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MASS’
```

Comment: You can run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` to update all packages built with versions of R older than your current one. It may take a while if you've got a lot of packages.

Comment: You seem to be using R v 3.2.5, and not v 3.2.2.  If this is the case, why is your default directory for installations still set at `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library` ? Maybe this is the reason for the problem you are describing.

Comment: @RHertel Thanks a lot for figuring this out. After I upgraded R to 3.2.5 somehow the installation was set to 3.2.2.. I restarted R Studio and then updated the library to 3.2.5 and the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for helping on this. Alistaire I used the command specified to update packages. Works like a charm. Thanks all.

Comment: @Doogle You're welcome. It's good to know that the problem is resolved.