# Running into an error when attempting to load MASS Package in R Studio but it loads fine in base R

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run `library(MASS)` I get the following error in R Studio:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
cannot open file 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/MASS/data/Rdata.rdb': No such file or directory
```

Yet it loads fine if I run the command in base R.

I can confirm as per the error message that the file (and the data folder) do not exist. But I've tried re-installing the MASS package (with apparent success) and it still doesn't appear to work.

I'm running R v3.3.1 both in base and in R Studio.

Comment: Do you know if the directory (and / or file) exists when you try to navigate to it ?  Are you using the same version of R both in RStudio and on the command line (you should confirm this) ?  When you installed `MASS` are you doing something like `install.packages('MASS', dependencies = TRUE)` ?  Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095916/unable-to-load-r-package-mass) with comments that may or may not help.

Comment: Do your Rapp and RStudio also use the same directory (`.libPaths()`) for packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not too burdensome, try removing RStudio and removing the RStudio-Desktop directory

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554736-How-To-Uninstall-RStudio

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

After reinstalling RStudio, try importing MASS.

Comment: Reinstalling R Studio and removing the directory has solved it. I don't understand why the issue occurred, but at least I know what to do next time I run into it. Thanks.